# Java - String.format , skip if null

Tags: java, string.format

By default `String.format()` will insert the actual word "null" if one of the strings to be injected is null.

For example :

```
String name = null;
String hello = String.format("Hello %s !", name );
```

The value of hello will be `"Hello null !"`

Is there a way to make `String.format()` skip the string if it is null, so I don't have the ugly "null" in there? So that the String in my example is `"Hello  !"`

Or

Is there another option in other libraries?
Thanks!

Comment: How about `String.format("Hello %s !", name==null ? "" : name);`?